# Why is wsl (windows subsystem for linux) not available in command prompt when prompt started from the Visual Studio 2019 IDE?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-subsystem-for-linux

If I start a command prompt from the menu within Visual Studio 2019 then wsl is not availble (and not simply missing a PATH for it):

```
>wsl
'wsl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

>dir \windows\system32\wsl.*
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is FE44-8F04

 Directory of c:\windows\system32

File Not Found
```

If I start a command prompt from start menu (even if I run vcvarsall.bat)

```
>wsl
My WSL Settings are working
alexp@LT-ALEXP-02:/mnt/c/workspace$

>dir \windows\system32\wsl.*
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is FE44-8F04

 Directory of C:\windows\system32

04/10/2019  04:58           142,848 wsl.exe
               1 File(s)        142,848 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  518,974,992,384 bytes free
```

This actually applies to a lot of files in the system32 dir (count of files about 2000 different between the 2 environments) but I noticed this trying to use wsl since I use that a lot in windows command prompt to access bash utilities / tools.

wsl is availble if I start "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019" from start menu - its only missing if I start this from the "Tools->Visual Studio Command Prompt" menu item within the IDE(and same behaviour in a powershell prompt started from same menu as well)

I'm using the professional edition of Visual Studio but a colleague reproduced the same issue and I believe he was using the community edition.

Anyone got any ideas what is happening here (and how to fix it)?

Answer (score 4):

Should probably have looked some more before asking.

Thanks to https://aigeec.com/using-windows-10-anniversary-bash-with-visual-studio-code/ for providing the clue.

EDIT: Original Site 404s [still available](https://web.archive.org/web/20200809110149/https://aigeec.com/using-windows-10-anniversary-bash-with-visual-studio-code/) on Archive.org

Visual Studio is 32 bit and I'm on a 64 bit OS so system32 is being redirected.

Path in "\windows\sysnative" and wsl and friends are suddenly availble.

Comment: The provided link is not available

Comment: OMG this was driving me nuts.  Thanks for the clue. I was building .net app and copy pasted code from another (Any CPU) and wsl was invalid.  Set to x64 and we good.